# dojo how i can check selected tab to Boolean Type.

Tags: dojo

i'm currently create a program that i would like to add any widget selected tab. so i must know information about the selected tab. but i don't know..
how i know selected tab the information that boolean type?

for example:

```
if(tabs.selected==true){...}
```

mycode

```
<div id="tabContainer" data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/TabContainer"
        data-dojo-props="region: 'bottom', tabPosition: 'top'"
        style="height: 700px;">
        <div data-dojo-type="dijit/layout/ContentPane" title="Form" id="content"  class="tab" >
            <h4>Example</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the `dijit/layout/TabContainer` has a property called [`selectedChildWidget`](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.9/dijit/layout/TabContainer#1_9dijit_layout_TabContainer_selectedChildWidget) which holds a reference to the active tab.

So, to validate if a tab is the active tab, you can do the following:

```js
var selectedTab = registry.byId("tabContainer").get("selectedChildWidget"),
    tab1 = registry.byId("content"));
if (selectedTab === tab1) {
    // "content" is the selected tab
}
```

A full example can be found on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tEbs9/

Comment: Thanks So Much!!!!!!!!Advice you gave me exactly what I was looking for solution. Thank you so much ...T.T thank you!!!!!i solved my ploblem!

Comment: ask for something!!^^ for example, tabContainer have contentpane that have content attribute as string. when the string is gridcontainer tag, how to get the id of gridcontainer?

Comment: What do you mean? Can you provide some code please (make a new question if it's something else than your current question).

Comment: I registered a new question. check please! thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this one could help you.
[dijit focus](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/focus.html)

You will be able to focus or track elements.

**example from the dojo docs:**
Try this code, it's also from the docs.

```
require([ "dijit/focus" ], function(focusUtil){
  focusUtil.on("widget-focus", function(widget){
    console.log("Focused widget", widget);
  });
  focusUtil.on("widget-blur", function(widget){
    console.log("Blurred widget", widget);
  });
});
```